# Can I use the Narrator Natural Voices added in Windows 11 in System.Speech.Synthesis?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.8

I want to add TTS in WPF through the SpeechSynthesizer provided by System.Speech.Synthesis.

But, the natural voices added in Windows 11 are not newly added even though more voice additions are downloaded.

Is it possible to use natural speech through SpeechSynthesizer in the existing local rather than by subscribing to Azure and calling an API key?

I checked the list with GetInstalledVoices(), but no new voices were added.